# Applying for Blue card in Germany - Change in Employment contract date

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have applied for Employment visa from India with first week of July as Employment start date. I have got the visa for first 3 months and moved to Germany. Since there is a delay in starting the Project, the Employer wants to change the Contract start date to first week of September. The employer suggests to use the new Contract to apply for Blue card in Germany.

I have been taking German language course during this time. I work in IT.

Will this change in Employment start date cause any issues with my Blue card application? Please suggest.